# VS2019 alignas in struct definition overrules pragma pack

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am trying to pack the structure "Test" using #pragma pack.

In VS2019 16.7.2, the following static assertion fails.

```
struct alignas(4 * sizeof(float)) Vec4
{
    float x,y,z,w;
};

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct Test
{
    char f;
    Vec4 vec;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

static_assert(sizeof(Test) == sizeof(char) + sizeof(Vec4), "Incorrect size.");
```

The size of Test is 2*sizeof(Vec4), which shows that the alignas on the struct definition itself overrules the pack.

The static assertion does not fail with GCC 10.2 or Clang 11.0.0.

Does anyone know of a way to pack Test as desired ? (without altering the alignment of the Vec4 struct)

Thanks.

Ben

Comment: "to pack Test as desired ? (without altering the alignment of the Vec4 struct)" --> change order: `vec` then `f` might work. Hmmm

Comment: Think this is the expected behavior, along the same line [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/alignment-cpp-declarations?view=vs-2019) "*when multiple alignas specifiers are encountered, the compiler will choose the strictest one, (the one with the largest value)**.

Answer (score 1):

`#pragma`s are implementation-defined. ISO C++ Standard says only this about them:

> **Pragma directive** [[cpp.pragma]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.pragma#:preprocessing_directives,pragma)
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# pragma` *pp-tokens*<sub>opt</sub> *new-line*
>
> causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined
> manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the
> translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming
> manner. Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is
> ignored.

So it's irrelevant that GCC or Clang implement `#pragma pack` in a certain way, apparently VC++ implements `#pragma pack` in a way that takes `alignas` directives into account. At warning level 4 it even issues a warning:

> **warning [C4324](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4324?view=vs-2019): 'Test': structure was padded due to alignment specifier**

MSDN further [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=vs-2019) that

> Without `__declspec(align(#))`, the compiler generally aligns data on natural boundaries based on the target processor and the size of the data, up to 4-byte boundaries on 32-bit processors, and 8-byte boundaries on 64-bit processors. Data in classes or structures is aligned in the class or structure at the minimum of its natural alignment and the current packing setting (from `#pragma pack` or the `/Zp` compiler option).

Which suggests that `#pragma pack` only affects the default alignment, and that `alignas` overrides it. And

> `__declspec(align(#))` can only increase alignment restrictions.

So it seems once `alignas` is set to `16` for `Vec4`, it can't be decreased (without altering the declaration of the `Vec4` struct).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am indeed aware that packing is not part of the standard.
Do you know if there is another way in which I can achieve my desired layout of "Test" ?